# Outbound IIS Rewrite Rule to set Content Type Response Header

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

Trying to get IIS to rewrite the response content type from image/jpeg to application/octet-stream for requests to resources like this:

```
http://www.example.org/path/to/images/some-image.jpg#download
```

to respond with the content type of application/octet-stream so browsers will prompt for download. I'm trying not to have to write a handler in the application to do it and having IIS do it would be easier.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="Download Photos" preCondition="Photo Images">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE" pattern="image/jpeg" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="application/octet-stream" />
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
        <preCondition name="Photo Images">
            <add input="{REQUEST_LOCATION}" pattern="photos/.*\.jpg\?#download$" />
        </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
</outboundRules>
```

Comment: May be easy to change MIME type in the "MIME types" section" for desired directory and extension, without using urlrewrite?

Comment: The tough part about this is that I only need this for specific resources, not all of them. Probably just end up writing custom handler, take less time than trying to write the rules for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `#` is available in the browser only. The server can not read it. You can read more about that in Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier